# Render ggplotly() in R Markdown github_document

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-plotly, ggplotly

Interactive graphs created with `ggplotly()` go along nicely with `html_document` output in R Markdown, see eg. [RMarkdown and ggplotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819837/rmarkdown-and-ggplotly). For `github_document` output, however, the knitted HTML preview file does not show `ggplotly()` graphs.

I adopted the code from the linked SO post and only changed the output format in the header. Does anyone know how to render **plotly** graphs correctly with this kind of output? Or at least, if that is even possible?

````
---
title: "RmarkdownExample"
author: "fdetsch"
date: "April 16, 2020"
output: github_document
---

Here is the graph I generated. 

```{r setup, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE}
# Require
library(plotly)
# Create
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
# Plot
g <- qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
# Call
ggplotly(g)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For `output: github_document`, I found a [workaround](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/90) that renders `ggplotly()` graphs nicely using iframes. The trick is to export the **plotly** widget as HTML and subsequently embed it as iframe. In my opinion, the advantage over `output: html_document` with `keep_md` enabled is that the online .md file simply prints a link to the intermediary HTML file instead of the full widget code, making it much tidier.

````
---
title: "Render `ggplotly()` graphs in `github_document`"
author: "fdetsch"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: github_document
---

Here is the graph I generated. 

```{r setup, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
# Require
library(plotly)
# Create
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
# Plot
g <- qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
# Call
p <- ggplotly(g)

```

```{r include, echo = FALSE}
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, "index.html")

htmltools::tags$iframe(
  src=file.path(getwd(), "index.html"),
  width="100%",
  height="600",
  scrolling="no",
  seamless="seamless",
  frameBorder="0"
)

```
````

At least when opening the preview HTML in an external viewer, the interactive graph shows up. The RStudio (preview version 1.3.938) viewer currently fails to render the image.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some problems with github_document, see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1311). My workaround: knit to `html_document` and save the resulting *.md-file.
So the YAML header is:

```
---
title: "RmarkdownExample"
author: "fdetsch"
date: "April 16, 2020"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

You can then use the md file to upload to github.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards this thread. I agree that the HTML renders nicely. However, the [online .md](https://github.com/fdetsch/knitr-playground/blob/master/R/render_ggplotly_github_document.md) looks quite messy.

Comment: True. I found a workaround for `output: github_document` and also shared the code. Honestly, I think that both answers have their justified place here, which makes it hard to accept one over the other..